# dealing with non-serializable Guava EventBus in Vaadin with session serialization

Tags: java, session, serialization, vaadin, guava

I'm creating a Vaadin Application and, based on the QuickTickets demo application and other examples, I decided to use Guava's `EventBus` for event handling, so I'm keeping a reference to it at the `UI` instance level.

Since I'm also using Spring Boot with DevTools, which can reload an application without needing a cold start, I discovered that Guava's `EventBus` is not `Serializable`, leading to `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

How can this be avoided?

For example:

1. Is there a way to make a `Serializable` wrapper around `EventBus`?  It would need to keep a list of registered event listeners and re-register them to the `EventBus` at session reload time (and I guess it needs a `transient` reference to `EventBus` so it doesn't get serialized).
2. Since I'm using Spring anyway, maybe I can make the `EventBus` a UI-scoped `Bean`?  I guess I still need to handle the re-registering of listeners then some way.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get vaadin running in a shared session environment I also had to face this problem. Together with Jose's great SerializableProxy-annotation and a fix  of vaadin's spring integration library (also thanks to another implementation of xpoft) it seems to be possible to get it running.

You can find a sample application here: https://github.com/khauser/microservices4vaadin within the frontend microservice

There you find also an adjusted EventBus from the quickticket dashboard, which could be autowired/injected like:

```
@Autowired
@SerializableProxy
private MyEventBus myEventBus;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when working with spring and vaadin as most spring singletons are not serializables (or should not be serialized at all).

I wrote a small library, [jdal-aop](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop) to allow injecting directly any spring bean on vaadin UIs using serializable proxies.

Maybe you want to try it.

Comment: Do I need to use AspectJ if I use that library?  Also, how exactly does the re-registering of `EventBus` subscribers happen?

Comment: @herman No, you don't need AspectJ, it's a spring aop library. Please, post the actual bean declaration in the question. There are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not serialize EventBus as it will contain UI Component instances which should be recreated with new UI. If you want to avoid the exception you might simply create a wrapper `Serializable` class as you mentioned, make that class session scoped, and put EventBus in that class, marking as transient.

If you do not want session persistence at all (which is the key to a stateless application which should be replicated easily), put `server.session.persistent=false` to your `application.properties` file.